# Javascript how to filter arrays matching a keyword

Tags: javascript, search

I have a deeply nested array as follows:

```
{[{
    id: "1",
    experts: [
        {instruments: [{guitar: ["John", "Maria"], 
                         piano: ["Hans", "Sarah", "Nancy"] }],
         name: "Columbia Records", published: "1930"
        },
        {instruments: [{guitar: ["Pablo"], 
                        drums: ["Jeb", "Xiao"]} ],
         name: "Atlas Records", published: "1978"
        }
    ]
]},
{
    id: "2",
    experts: [
        {instruments: [{sitar: ["Anaka", "Reha"], 
                        chello: ["Hans", "Raphael", "Stuart"]} ],
         name: "Touchstone Records", published: "1991"
        },
        {instruments: [{viola: ["Richard", "Farah"], 
                        buss: ["Tina", "Max"]} ],
         name: "Atlas Records", published: "1978"
        }
    ]

}
```

I need to perform leveled search. For example if my search key is "Jo" the result should be:

```
[{
        id: "1",
        experts: [{"instruments": [
                                   "guitar": ["John"]
                                  ]              
                 ],
             "name": "Columbia Records", "published": "1930"
 }]
```

In other words each nested level, I just filter based on the key and if it does not exist then remove the nested object and go further. If the search key is "1" it will return the whole first object.

I am looking into loadsh and its filter function which takes a predicate but not sure how to achieve the search arbitrary nesting.

Comment: I'd say recursion is your friend here

Comment: This is not valid: `["guitar": ["John", "Maria"]`, provide your fixed code

Comment: And screwed up brackets `{[{id: "1"  /* ... */ ]]},`

Comment: have you checked out lodash? There are a lot of helpers that may be useful to you in this situation

Comment: In the first place, how do you have this complicated structures? It is not even valid I believe?

Answer (score 1):

It looked like fun so here. To begin with your object declaration had lots of errors. You were missing closing tags, and you don't create arrays with keys like `["key":"value"]`, that's for objects `{"key":"value"}`

```
var testArray = [{
    id: "1",
    experts: [
        {"instruments": {"guitar": ["John", "Maria"], 
                         "piano": ["Hans", "Sarah", "Nancy"] },
         "name": "Columbia Records", "published": "1930"
        },
        {"instruments": {"guitar": ["Pablo"], 
                         "drums": ["Jeb", "Xiao"] },
         "name": "Atlas Records", "published": "1978"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: "2",
    experts: [
        {"instruments": {"sitar": ["Anaka", "Reha"], 
                         "chello": ["Hans", "Raphael", "Stuart"] },
         "name": "Touchstone Records", "published": "1991"
        },
        {"instruments": {"viola": ["Richard", "Farah"], 
                         "buss": ["Tina", "Max"] },
         "name": "Atlas Records", "published": "1978"
        }
    ]
}];
```

One way is to use recursion, something as such:

```
function deepSearchForValue(obj, searchstring) {
  var doesValueExist = function(item) {
    if (typeof item === "string") {
      return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchstring.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    } else {
      return doesValueExistRecursive(item);
    }
  }

  var doesValueExistRecursive = function(item) {
     for (i in item) { 
        if (doesValueExist(item[i])) {
           return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }

  return obj.filter(doesValueExistRecursive);
}
```

And you would call it like so

```
var matchedItems = deepSearchForValue(testArray, "reh");

console.log("found:");
console.log(matchedItems);
```

Comment: Thanks! Very close to what I need, except I also want to pop the "chello": ["Hans", "Raphael", "Stuart"] as well. I guess I need another level of recursion?

Comment: What do you mean "pop the chello"? Yeah you could write another recursive function that deletes/deletes and returns items by key. You have the base there so it shouldn't be too tricky.

Answer (score 0):

you'd probably want something like this. May be a few modification in the algo gives you what you exactly are after:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    id: "1",
    experts: [
      {
        "instruments": {
          "guitar": ["John", "Maria"], 
          "piano": ["Hans", "Sarah", "Nancy"] 
        },
        "name": "Columbia Records", 
        "published": "1930"
      },
      {
        "instruments": {
          "guitar": ["Pablo"], 
          "drums": ["Jeb", "Xiao"]
        },
        "name": "Atlas Records", 
        "published": "1978"
      }
    ]
},
{
    id: "2",
    experts: [
        {
          "instruments": {
            "sitar": ["Anaka", "Reha"],
            "chello": ["Hans", "Raphael", "Stuart"]
          },
         "name": "Touchstone Records", 
         "published": "1991"
        },
        {
          "instruments": {
            "viola": ["Richard", "Farah"],
            "buss": ["Tina", "Max"]
          },
         "name": "Atlas Records", 
         "published": "1978"
        }
    ]
}];

var t = _.remove(arr, function(n) {
  if(!_.includes(n, 'Jo')){
    return n;
  }
});

document.getElementById('search').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(t);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="search"></div>
</body>
</html>
```